# Color interpolation between 3 colors

Tags: colors, interpolation, gradient

I use the following equation to get a nice color gradient from colorA to colorB, but I have no idea how to do the same for 3 colors, so the gradient goes from colorA to colorB to colorC

`colorT = colorA * p + colorB * (1.0 - p);` where "p" is the a percentage from 0.0 to 1.0

Thanks

Comment: Wouldn't you just calculate the gradient from colorA to colorB and then colorB to colorC?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, for 3 colors, you can just to the same with p = 0.0 to 2.0:

```
if p <= 1.0
  colorT = colorA * p + colorB * (1.0 - p);
else
  colorT = colorB * (p - 1.0) + colorC * (2.0 - p);
```

Or scale it so you can still use p = 0.0 to 1.0:

```
if p <= 0.5
  colorT = colorA * p * 2.0 + colorB * (0.5 - p) * 2.0;
else
  colorT = colorB * (p - 0.5) * 2.0 + colorC * (1.0 - p) * 2.0;
```

Comment: using this formla I get colorB to be drawn at p=0 and p=1 so the gradient goes from there to the middle making a jump right in the middle from colorA to colorC any ideas?

Comment: Fix it by changing A to B and B to C

Answer (score 4):

Thanks for the formula. But I had to make some modifications to it, as it didn't interpolate between the 3 colors properly (there was jumps in color change)

Here is the fix for that:

```
if (p < 0.5)
        {
            COLORx = (COLORb * p * 2.0) +  COLORa * (0.5 - p) * 2.0;
        }
        else
        {
            COLORx = COLORc * (p - 0.5) * 2.0 + COLORb * (1.0 - p) * 2.0;          
        }
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer since it was the only one I found, that really did the job. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

It might be possible to construct a single expression for that, but the simplest is to use a condition to use different expressions depending on whether you are in the A - B part or B - C part of the range:

```
colorT =
  p < 0.5
    ? colorA * p * 2.0 + colorB * (1.0 - p * 2.0)
    : colorB * (p - 0.5) * 2.0 + colorC * (1.0 - (p - 0.5) * 2.0);
```

Comment: Yeah, seems I saw it the same time you changed it.

Answer (score 1):

one possible solution is to use interpolation via Bézier Curve:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zier_curve
if you look at the special case Quadratic Bézier Curve, you can see a formula that interpolate between 3 points, or colors in your case.

```
colorT=(1-p*p)Color0 + 2(1-p)Color1 + (p*p)Color2   , 0<=p<=1
```

This is a generalization of your linear formula.

EDIT:

on second though, this method doesn't get your results, as the intermediate point is never touched.
To get a smooth curve that touch all of your points (colors) you have to use a spline http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spline_interpolation

Comment: Can you give a formula for a spline interpolation?

Comment: @AntonShkurenko well Spline Interpolation is really a family of solutions to a set of constrains . Depending of your requirement you can look at this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spline_interpolation#See_also section. Hermite is quite easy to write in code, you can try to look in that.

Answer (score 0):

You want to be able to create 3 color but equal gradients? Exactly the same: after you're done with this gradient, start a new one where colorA is the current colorB and colorB is the new color. Append the results and you're done:

colorA ---- colorB colorB ---- colorC

Good luck!