# Java color interpolation between 3 stops

Tags: java, math, colors, interpolation

I have a function that I pass r g and b to that then returns a color, r g and b are between 0.0 and 1.0.

I need to interpolate the colors I pass the function from red to yellow to green, based on a percentage from 0.0 to 1.0.

I found this other SO answer [Color interpolation between 3 colors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5406681/color-interpolation-between-3-colors) but I'm not sure how I would apply it to my case.

Comment: @JordiCastilla I haven't been able to try anything, I have no idea on where to even start. Color interpolation stuff is really new to me. I guess this question isn't exactly SO quality, but this is the only place I know to ask for help

Comment: you're right here.... The point is, maybe you cannot reach color interpolation, thats ok.... But, **get started**: make a layout or some shape to put color, make button to start interpolation and try something... after when you get stuck you will have a nice SO question

Comment: This in't exactly what you want, but it solves the same sort of problem: http://sourceforge.net/p/tus/code/HEAD/tree/tjacobs/ui/ex/ColorGradient.java#l139

Comment: @ControlAltDel I don't see how that applies to what I'm trying to do?

Comment: The way to actually do n-stops color interpolation is that you divide 0 to 1 into intervalls and interpolate two colors depending on in which interval p falls into. I described the process on http://mroman.ch/guides/interpolateclr.html

Comment: @mroman thank you for taking time to comment on this old question of mine! I'm working on a completely unrelated project to the original question that involves color interpolation and your comment/article helped immensely  :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use the following function to simulate colors vary from red then yellow to finally green:

```
public Color getColor(float p){
    return new Color(1.0-p,p,0);
}
```

where getColor(0) returns red, getColor(0.5) returns yellow, getColor(1.0) returns green

Comment: Worked perfect sir :) Thanks for you help

Comment: how can you increase the sepctrum? https://www.w3schools.com/colors/colors_picker.asp#huecontainer